# condition probability of a condition probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Given a probability space ($\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P}$).Suppose A $\in\mathscr{F}$ satisfies $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$.Define $\mathbb{Q}(B):=\mathbb{P}(B|A)$ for any B$\in\mathscr{F}$.Prove for any $B\in\mathscr{F}$ and sub $\sigma$ algebra $\mathscr{C}\subset\mathscr{F}$,
$\mathbb{Q}(B|\mathscr{C})=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A,B|\mathscr{C})}{\mathbb{P}(A|\mathscr{C})}$.

I think, we must proof $\forall C\in\mathscr{C}$,$\mathbb{Q}(B,C)=\int_C\frac{\mathbb{P}(A,B|\mathscr{C})}{\mathbb{P}(A|\mathscr{C})}$,but I don't know how to calculate the last integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP asked Speltzu for an explanation I add how I would prove this:

By definition:
$$\tag1
\mathbb Q(B)=\mathbb P(B|A)=\frac{\mathbb P(B\cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)}\,.
$$
***Claim.*** *For a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr C$ we have
$$\tag2
\boxed{\phantom{\Bigg|}\quad\mathbb Q\big[B\,\big|\,\mathscr C\big]=\frac{\mathbb P[B\cap A\,|\,\mathscr C]}{\mathbb P[A\,|\,\mathscr C]}\,.\quad}
$$
Proof.* By defintion of the conditional probability we have
for any $C\in\mathscr C$
$$\tag3
\int_C\mathbb P\big[B\cap A\,\big|\,\mathscr C\big]\,d\mathbb P=\mathbb P\big[B\cap A\cap C\big]\,.
$$
The measure $\mathbb Q$ has Radon-Nikodym density
$$\tag4
\frac{d\mathbb Q}{d\mathbb P}=\frac{1_A}{\mathbb P(A)}
$$
with respect to $\mathbb P\,.$
Then,
\begin{align}\tag5\require{cancel}
&\int_C \frac{\mathbb P[B\cap A\,|\,\mathscr C]}{\mathbb P[A\,|\,\mathscr C]}\,d\mathbb Q\stackrel{(4)}{=}
\int_C\,\frac{\mathbb P[B\cap A\,|\,\mathscr C]}{\mathbb P[A\,|\,\mathscr C]}\,\frac{1_A}{\mathbb P(A)}\,d\mathbb P\\[2mm]\tag6
&\stackrel{\textstyle\color{red}{(*)}}=
\int_C\,\frac{\mathbb P[B\cap A\,|\,\mathscr C]}{\cancel{\mathbb P[A\,|\,\mathscr C]}}\frac{\cancel{\mathbb P[A\,|\,\mathscr C]}}{\mathbb P(A)}\,d\mathbb P\\[2mm]\tag7
&=\int_C\,\frac{\mathbb P[B\cap A\,|\,\mathscr C]}{\mathbb P(A)}\,d\mathbb P
\stackrel{(3)}{=}
\frac{\mathbb P[B\cap A\cap C]}{\mathbb P(A)}\stackrel{(1)}=\mathbb Q(B\cap C)\,. 
\end{align}
$$\tag*{
$\Box$}
\phantom{\quad}
$$

To answer the question by Speltzu why in the equals sign marked by
$\color{red}{(*)}$ we are allowed to switch from $1_A$ to
$\mathbb P[A\,|\,{\mathscr C}]\,:$

All other ingredients of that integral are ${\mathscr C}$-measurable. The very definition of $\mathbb P[A|{\mathscr C}]$ says
$$\tag8
\int_\Omega 1_C\mathbb P[A\,|\,{\mathscr C}]\,d\mathbb P=\int_\Omega 1_C1_A\,d\mathbb P\,,\quad \forall C\in{\mathscr C}\,.$$
This carries over from the indicator function $1_C$ to all simple ${\mathscr C}$-measurable functions and then to all ${\mathscr C}$-measurable functions.

Comment: How do you justify the change of $\mathbb{P}[A|\mathscr{C}]$ for $1_A$?

Comment: @Speltzu See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult problem where there are. I rectify my previous answer. The proposition is true.The reasoning would be as follows:
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left[\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B|\mathscr{C}]}{\mathbb{P}[A|\mathscr{C}]}. 1_C\right]
=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left[\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B\cap C|\mathscr{C}]}{\mathbb{P}[A|\mathscr{C}]}\right]
=\int \left[\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B\cap C|\mathscr{C}]}{\mathbb{P}[A|\mathscr{C}]}\right]d\mathbb{P}_{\Omega/A}=\\
=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)}\int 1_A.\left[\frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B\cap C|\mathscr{C}]}{\mathbb{P}[A|\mathscr{C}]}\right]d\mathbb{P}_{\Omega}
=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)}\int \mathbb{P}[A\cap B\cap C|\mathscr{C}]d\mathbb{P}_{\Omega}=\\
=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\mathbb{Q}(B\cap C)
=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}[1_B.1_C]
\end{gather*}
By the way, this means that:
$\mathbb{Q}[B|\mathscr{C}]=\mathbb{P}[B|\mathscr{C},A]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please explain the equation when $B\notin \mathscr{C}$ ?